# word macro returning error about tool grammar

Tags: vba, ms-word

for some reason, when I'm running this VBA macro code:

```
Sub dor()

    Dim DocStats As String
    Dim MBTitle As String
    Dim J As Integer


    With Selection
    .WholeStory
    .LanguageID = wdEnglishUS
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    End With


    MBTitle = "Readability Statistics"
    DocStats = ""
    With ActiveDocument.Content
        For J = 1 To 10
            'DocStats = DocStats & .ReadabilityStatistics(J)
            'DocStats = DocStats & ": "
            DocStats = DocStats & .ReadabilityStatistics(J).Value
            DocStats = DocStats & vbCrLf
        Next J
    End With


    '~ Create a FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    '~ Provide file path
    outFile = "C:\Users\Dor\Desktop\UrisJobs\work_prod\docx\all_files\output\" & ActiveDocument.Name & ".txt"


    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim objFile As Object
    Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(outFile, True, True)

    '~ Setting up file to write
    '~ Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, True)


    strComputer = "."


        'Wscript.Echo objFile.Name  'Commented out

        '~ Write to file
    objFile.WriteLine DocStats


    '~ Close the file
    objFile.Close


End Sub
```

I'm getting this error:

> "tool grammar statistics array cannot be run on a document that contains more than one language format"

I don't know why, but for some documents my code is working and for some - I'm getting this error.

Comment: Which version of Word is this? Even though a specific language is applied to the entire document via the `Selection` object it does happen that the language formatting is not applied throughout. In some versions of Word a language format that was applied by Word - because the Word and WIndows language formats don't match - can't be overridden. My best guess would be that that's what's happening.

Comment: @CindyMeister office 2016